# Chart.js stepSize not working with min

Tags: chart.js

min is not considered for StepSize.

including fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4p93aew7/10/

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 23, 15, 32, 33],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [17, 11, 25, 18, 13, 37],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 5,
          max: 40,
          stepSize: 8
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

In the example, step size is 8 and min is 5, so each step should be 8 **starting from 5** but it clearly isn't. How do I fix this?

**Edit**: For those who wants to follow this issue. Here is a [github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5644) link

Comment: @Edit: included jsfiddle as snipped

Comment: This looks like a typo. In your snippet you have `stepSize: 8`. Change it to `stepSize: 7` and the scale works correctly.

Comment: @timclutton Please see the included fiddle

Comment: @KarthikNarayan Your fiddle also has a `stepSize: 8`. Again, changing it to `stepSize: 7` fixes the issue. See your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p93aew7/17/).

Comment: @timclutton why is it not working for stepsize 8? I guess only 7 is working correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js yAxes Ticks stepSize not working (fiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897653/chart-js-yaxes-ticks-stepsize-not-working-fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

You're forcing a `min`, a `max`, and a `stepSize` that don't work together. The auto-scaling algorithm is doing its best achieve what you ask, but something has to give.

If you really want it work cleanly you need to ensure the range (`max`-`min`) is cleanly divisible by the `stepSize`. E.g.:

```
40-5 = 35
35/7 = 5
```

5 is a whole number, so the scale will work.

```
35/8 = 4.375
```

4.375 isn't a whole number so the scale won't work.

If you make `max` 45 then

```
45-5 = 40
40/8 = 5
```

Again, 5 is a whole number and the scale will work.